# MVC3 Model Binding Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this strange issue in MVC 3.

I have a strongly typed view and a controller which has a SaveMethod(Employee emp).

But when i click SAVE, it is not hitting Save method and throws below error.

I think there may be a model binder issue. But how i know which property is a problem?

Its difficult for me to find a property from 50

**Exception:**

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`

**Source**: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

**StackTrace**

at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.d_*1.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.d*_5.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

How do i check which property causes this issue?

Comment: show your code. and the error is clearly descriptive.

Comment: Post your controller action method

Comment: Show your controller code and your view model as well. We will help you to investigating this issue

Answer (score 9):

Looks to me like you've applied a [StringLength] to an integer property on your model:

```
public class MyModel {
  [StringLength]
  public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

That will throw the kind of error that you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Look in your model if you have the `StringLength` attribute applied to a property of type `int`.